# Any built-in fmap-of-sorts on all values of a tuple?

Tags: haskell

For now I have this little helper:

```
both f (one,two) = (f one , f two)
```

Then I was idly wondering whether `fmap` "iterates" a tuple so I asked GHCi:

```
fmap reverse ("aA","bB")
```

Result being:

```
("aA","Bb")
```

Odd! So the semantics of fmap over a tuple seems to be "to apply func to the snd", if you will.

Anything in `base` or `Prelude` I should use instead of my own `both`? Hoogle gave [no promising results](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(t1%20-%3E%20t)%20-%3E%20(t1%2C%20t1)%20-%3E%20(t%2C%20t)) or I parsed them wrongly.

Comment: "Odd!" - it's actually the only possible implementation, but the syntax for the tuple type which puns on the data constructor sort of hides it. More straightforward would be: `data Tuple a b = Tuple a b` ; `instance Functor (Tuple a)` ... so the concrete type signature for `fmap` on tuples is (with redundant parens for clarity): `fmap :: (b -> c) -> (Tuple a) b -> (Tuple a) c` where `Tuple a` is your `f`.

Comment: I will validate that this "last type parameter" business was indeed very odd looking when I first encountered it.  Haskell is somewhat sensitive to the order of parameters, especially type parameters, which is quite different from basically every other language where it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of "mapping" over both elements of a tuple, the best you have is `bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d` defined in [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) (now in `base`!). With that, you can write

```
ghci> bimap reverse reverse ("aA","bB")
("Aa","Bb")
```

Alternately, you can use `(***) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')` defined in [`Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html) (in particular using the `Arrow (->)` instance). With that, you can write

```
ghci> (reverse *** reverse) ("aA","bB")
("Aa","Bb")
```

However, if you are trying to map over both elements of a tuple at the same time, perhaps you are looking for an abstraction that groups together two values of type `a`. If this is the case, I would recommend you use a `newtype` around `(a,a)`. Then, you can turn on the `-XDeriveFunctor` extension as get the following

```
ghci> :set -XDeriveFunctor
ghci> newtype Pair a = Pair (a,a) deriving (Show,Functor)
ghci> fmap reverse (Pair ("aA","bB"))
Pair ("Aa","Bb")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to consider the full type. In the type `(a,b)`, which is the same a s `(,) a b`, the functor is `(,) a`. Hence we get

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> (,) a b -> (,) a c
```

This makes it clear that the first component is unaffected by `fmap`.

```
> fmap reverse (True,"bB")
(True,"Bb")
```

You are probably thinking of another functor

```
-- user-defined
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving Functor
```

Here we do have

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> Pair b -> Pair c
```

affecting both components, but this type is not the regular tuple type.

Bonus puzzle: for the same reason

```
> length (1,2)
1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly an overkill for this particular example, and it's not in base, but most generic programming libraries will let you do that. E.g. with [traverse-with-class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/traverse-with-class-0.2.0.4/docs/Data-Generics-Traversable.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
import Data.Generics.Traversable
import Data.Proxy

main = do
  -- specify the constraint to make 'reverse' type-check.
  -- (~) String means "equal to String"
  let ?c = Proxy :: Proxy ((~) String)
  print $ gmap reverse ("aA","bB")
```

Answer (score 4):

As Alec indicated, `bimap` is good for pairs. If you want to deal with tuples more generally, one option is to use a class. The below was inspired by some ideas in `lens` (especially [`Control.Lens.Tuple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html)), but I don't think it's quite the same as anything there.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Tuplish where
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity (..))
import Data.Profunctor.Unsafe ((#.), (.#))

class Tuply s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  ttraverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t

mapTuple :: Tuply s t a b => (a -> b) -> (s -> t)
mapTuple = (runIdentity .) #. ttraverse .# (Identity .)


instance (a1 ~ a, a2 ~ a, b1 ~ b, b2 ~ b)
    => Tuply (a1, a2) (b1, b2) a b where
  ttraverse f (x,y) = (,) <$> f x <*> f y

instance (a1 ~ a, a2 ~ a, a3 ~ a, b1 ~ b, b2 ~ b, b3 ~ b)
    => Tuply (a1,a2,a3) (b1,b2,b3) a b where
  ttraverse f (x,y,z) = (,,) <$> f x <*> f y <*> f z

instance (a1 ~ a, a2 ~ a, a3 ~ a, a4 ~ a, b1 ~ b, b2 ~ b, b3 ~ b, b4 ~ b)
    => Tuply (a1,a2,a3,a4) (b1,b2,b3,b4) a b where
  ttraverse f (x,y,z,w) = (,,,) <$> f x <*> f y <*> f z <*> f w

instance (a1 ~ a, a2 ~ a, a3 ~ a, a4 ~ a, a5 ~ a,
          b1 ~ b, b2 ~ b, b3 ~ b, b4 ~ b, b5 ~ b)
    => Tuply (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5) a b where
  ttraverse f (x,y,z,w,u) = (,,,,) <$> f x <*> f y <*> f z <*> f w <*> f u

instance (a1 ~ a, a2 ~ a, a3 ~ a, a4 ~ a, a5 ~ a, a6 ~ a,
          b1 ~ b, b2 ~ b, b3 ~ b, b4 ~ b, b5 ~ b, b6 ~ b)
    => Tuply (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6) (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6) a b where

  ttraverse f (x,y,z,w,u,v) = (,,,,,) <$> f x <*> f y <*> f z <*> f w <*> f u <*> f v
```

Comment: [That `lens` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html), for reference